# MediaPlayerでrawフォルダの音声ファイルが再生できない

Tags: android

```
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/R.raw." + name));
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

上記のようにしてrawフォルダの音声ファイルを再生させようとすると、以下のようなエラーが返ってきます。

```
Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
D/MediaPlayer﹕ create failed: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

これはMediaPlayer.createの引数のUriが間違っているのでしょうか？
原因が分からず詰まってしまっており、ぜひお力添えをいただきたいと思います。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 「Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + name)」としてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘通りの方法で試してみたところ、「D/MediaPlayer﹕ start() mUri is android.resource://mypackage/2131034116」というエラーが返ってきてしまいます。。。

Comment: ちなみに、name に入るファイル名に拡張子(.mp3 など)は含まれていますか?

Comment: 確認したところ、拡張子は含まれてませんでした。

Comment: 了解です。たびたびですみませんが、「Uri.parse("android.resource://mypackage/raw/song")」としてみて、再生されるかどうか確かめていただけますか？(songの部分はrawフォルダにあるものを指定して下さい)

Comment: タグをmediaplayerからmedia-playerに変更しました。

Comment: songの部分をrawフォルダにあるものを指定すると、音声は再生されませんでした。...ということは再生のさせ方自体が間違っているのでしょうか？ちなみに拡張子はm4aとなっております。

Comment: 拡張子を指定しなくても再生されないのですね？それと、何かエラーメッセージは表示されましたでしょうか？

Comment: はい、再生されませんでした。エラーメッセージは「D/MediaPlayer﹕ start() mUri is android.resource://mypackage/raw/2131034112」というエラーが返ってきます。

Comment: @kojianu this を getApplicationContext() にしてみていただけますか？

Comment: thisをgetApplicationContextにしてみたのですが、「start() mUri is null」というエラーが返ってきてしまいました。。。

Comment: なかなか手強いですね。。。何か分かったらまたコメントします。

Comment: 了解しました。ありがとうございます。こちらも粘ってみようと思います。

Comment: 申し訳ありません！解決でき、原因を申し上げにくいのですが、Android端末の音量が0だったことが原因でした......。本当に申し訳ありません。ログに「start() mUri is null」と出続けているので再生されてないものと思い込んでました。このようなことでお手を煩わせてしまって、大変申し訳ございませんでした。親切に対応してくださり、とても感謝しています。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @kojianu いえいえ、解決できて良かったです。ちなみにですが、Uri.parse(〜) を使っても再生は可能でしょうか？

Comment: はい、再生することができました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下の方法でrawフォルダ内の音声ファイルを再生させることができました。

```
int mediaResource = getResources().getIdentifier(soundFileName, "raw", getPackageName());
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), mediaResource);
```

getIdentifierメソッドの第一引数にはrawフォルダ内の再生したい音声ファイル名を指定します。（sound1.mp3を再生させたければ "sound1" と書く）
ちなみに以下の方法でも音声を再生することができました。

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + soundFileName)
```

また、僕の場合はAndroid端末の音量が0だったことも原因でした。音声が再生されていてもログに「start() mUri is null」と出るので、てっきり音声が再生されてないものと思い込んでいました。
もし上記のようにコードを書いて音声が鳴らなければ、端末の音量を確認してみるのもいいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

[MediaPlayer.create(Context context, int resid)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) という他のファクトリーメソッドがあるので、そちらを使った方が手っ取り早いのではないでしょうか？

```
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.voice);
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。今回の場合ですとR.raw以下は直接指定したくないのですが、試しにR.raw以下を直接指定して再生させてみると、「start() mUri is null」というエラーが返ってきました。これはやはり再生のさせ方に問題があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648722/how-to-access-a-video-from-the-raw-folder-using-a-variableの回答にあるように](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648722/how-to-access-a-video-from-the-raw-folder-using-a-variable%E3%81%AE%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%AB%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB)、R.raw.hogehogeのhogehogeを自由に切り替える方法は一手間必要です。

うまく言えませんが、文字列で間接参照？のようなことはJava の仕様ではできないはず…

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。R.raw以下の文字列は自由に切り替えれないのですね。リンク先に書いてあることを参考に実装し直したのですが、「D/MediaPlayer﹕ start() mUri is android.resource://mypackage/2131034116」というエラーが返ってきました。

Comment: @kojianu
既に解決されていたのでしたら申し訳ございませんが、
Uriを使用する場合、以下の方法でいけそうです。
```
int mediaResource = getResources().
    getIdentifier(name, "raw", getPackageName());
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, mediaResource);
mMediaPlayer.start();
```
浅学で申し訳ないのですが、
Uriを使用して掲題にあるようなやり方をする場合、
[MediaPlayerの状態遷移](http://umezo.hatenablog.jp/entry/20100531/1275319329)にあるように、`create`で一発で済むのではなく[setDataSource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource)で設定して`prepare`を呼んで、とInitializeの状態まで持っていくのが大変ってことみたいです。

Comment: 詳しい解説誠にありがとうございます。ご提示いただいた方法で実装し直してみると、「D/MediaPlayer﹕ start() mUri is null」というエラーが返ってきました。getIdentifierメソッドの第一引数のnameには再生させるrawフォルダ内の音声ファイル名を指定するのですよね？その際に拡張子は必要でしょうか？

Comment: 音声ファイルの命名規則に問題がありそうな気がしてきました。[res/rawのリソースのIdを使おうとするとエラーが出る](http://woshidan.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/01/27/221731)などご参照の上、@hataさんの方法でご確認してはいかがでしょうか。お力に全くなれず申し訳ございません。