# Twitterで投稿する際の添付画像をDrawableフォルダから選択する

Tags: android, twitter4j

以前よりTwitterで投稿する際に`Drawable`フォルダから画像を指定して投稿する方法が分からず困っています。そもそもそういうことができるのでしょうか？
Twitterに画像を投稿する際は`File`指定しないといけないので、現在は以下のように一旦内部ストレージに画像を保存してからTwitterに画像を投稿させているのですが、新たに画像を添付させるためにはこういう方法しかないのでしょうか？どなたか分かる方がいればお助けいただきたいです。すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

画像保存

```
    public void createImageFile() {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/image.png";
        File file = new File(path);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path, false);
                Bitmap bitmap = TwitterContents.getInstance().getmImage();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

画像付きツイート

```
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/image.png");
            StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(params[0]); {
                status.setMedia(file);
            }
            mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下のようなコードにすることで、`res/drawable`にある画像をツイートに添付できるようになりました。

```
    public void share() {
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>() {
            InputStream inputStream;

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    inputStream = mActivity.getResources().openRawResource(+ R.drawable.androidlogo);
                    StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(params[0]);
                    status.setMedia("androidlogo", inputStream);
                    mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
                    return true;
                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                } finally {
                    try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

掲題の`画像付きツイート`について、[Twitter4Jのメソッドで、引数にinputStreamを取るsetMedia](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/StatusUpdate.html#setMedia-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-)があるらしいので書き換えてみました。
動かしてないので動作保証はできないです。予め申し訳ありません。
[Create a file from drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895073/create-a-file-from-drawable)の@muditさんの回答を参考にしています。

`drawable`フォルダの直下にimage.pngがあると仮定しています。

```
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.image);
        StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(params[0]);
        status.setMedia("iamge", inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

`R.drawable.image`は [MediaPlayerでrawフォルダの音声ファイルが再生できない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/4402/mediaplayer%E3%81%A7raw%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%80%E3%81%AE%E9%9F%B3%E5%A3%B0%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%8C%E5%86%8D%E7%94%9F%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) あたりを参照しつつ、適当に書き換えてください。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
上記の方法を参考に実装したところ、「NullpointerException」が返ってきてしまいました。ログを取ってみると「StatusUpdate」の「mediaFile」の項目が「null」となっており、「openRawResource」の引数の設定が間違っているものと予想しているのですが、このような感じで実装しました。
「InputStream inputStream = mActivity.getResources().openRawResource(+ R.drawable.androidlogo);」
また、試しにRawフォルダを作成してそのフォルダ内の画像を「openRawResource」に指定しても同じように「NullpointerException」が返ってきてしまいます。
一体どのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？
長々と申し訳ありません。すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 動かしていないのに、回答して申し訳ありません。まず、setMediaが悪いのかInputStreamが違うのか切り分けが必要だと思います。inputStreamがnullかどうか確認して下さい。その上でまずinputStreamについて。
drawableフォルダ直下にandroidlogo.pngを置いた場合、inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.androidlogo);となります。setMediaについて。第一引数が間違ってる可能性が多分にあります。"androidlogo"か"androidlogo.png"を、お試し下さい。お手数おかけ致しますが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: いえいえ、こちらこそありがとうございます。inputStreamはnullではなかったのですが、drawableで以下のように指定しようとすると「Expected resource of type raw」となり、赤い波線が引数に表示され指定できませんでした。
inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.androidlogo);
なのでRawフォルダを作成して、openRawResourceの引数に(R.raw.androidlogo)と指定しているのですが、rawフォルダでもよろしいでしょうか？setMediaの引数をご指摘の通りに変更したのですが、openRawResourceでの指定が間違っているせいか、まだうまく動いてません。

Comment: ごめんなさい。+指定でdrawableID を読むやり方を初めて知りました。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572647/android-openrawresource-not-working-for-a-drawable
こちらが勉強になって本当に申し訳ありません。はい、res/rawフォルダに置いて、idをR.id.androidlogoでもう一度お試しいただけますか。度々すみません…

Comment: いえいえ。res/rawフォルダに置いて、openRawResource(R.raw(id?).androidlogo)で試してみたのですが、やはりNullpointerExceptionが返ってきてしまいます。。。概ね現在のコードは以下のような感じです。
InputStream inputStream = mActivity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.androidlogo);
                    StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(params[0]);
                    status.setMedia("androidlogo", inputStream);
                    mTwitter.updateStatus(status);

Comment: お手数おかけして
申し訳ございません、穴が空くほどコードを見つめたのですが、手元に環境がないため、これ以上は全く分からないです。本当に申し訳ございません。。お昼時間を過ぎてしまったのでこれ以上回答も難しく……仕事が終わり次第、ご解決できなければ注進致しますのでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: InputStream#close()はTwitter#updateStatus()コール後のfinallyブロックで呼ばないといけないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: user3009331さん、いえいえ、ご親切に対応してくださり、本当に感謝しています。そしてuser3009331さんのお力添えもあり、無事解決することができました！詳細は自分で回答したいと思います。本当にありがとうございました。感謝しています。

Comment: Yuki Yoshidaさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通りfinallyブロックでuddateStatusを呼ぶと、無事投稿されました！本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決したようで何よりです。@Yuki Yoshidaさん、ありがとうございました。@kojianuさん、お手数おかけいたしました。精進します…